# Laravel duplicate entries when reload page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model ,a controller and a form for introducing entries to database.The problem is that refresing the page cause duplicate entries in database.How to resolv it?

loan.controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {   $id = Auth::id();
           $loan=New loan;
            $loan->cod_user=$id;
            $loan->nume =$request->name;
            $loan->data=$request->date;
            $loan->durata=$request->period;
            $loan->valoare_rata_luna=$request->month;
            $loan->valoare_totala=$request->amount;
            $loan->save();

            return view('loans');
        }
```

the form from loans view:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                     <div class="blacktext"><h3>My Loans:</h3></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                  <div class="col-md-2"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Loan</button></div>

               <div class="modal fade " id="modal1" role="dialog">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                        <div class="modal-content">

                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                                        <h3>Add Loan</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body text-right">

                               <form action="{{ route('loan.store') }}" method="POST">    
                                    <p class="al-left">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    <label for="date">Date:</label>
                                    <input type = "date" name="date" placeholder="Date" id="date">
                                    </p>

                                    ...

                                    <p class="al-left">
                                    <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
                                    <input type = "number" name="amount" placeholder="0" id="amount">
                                    </p>

                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="submit" value="Add">
```

Comment: try to redirect after saving the details rather then directly returning the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
return redirect()-back();
```

It will work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect to the route (the route which serves the view) instead of the view at the end of your store method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {   $id = Auth::id();
           $loan=New loan;
            $loan->cod_user=$id;
            $loan->nume =$request->name;
            $loan->data=$request->date;
            $loan->durata=$request->period;
            $loan->valoare_rata_luna=$request->month;
            $loan->valoare_totala=$request->amount;
            $loan->save();

            return redirect(route(('loans')); //asumming that you named a route as loans
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

POST still exists upon refresh .. what you can do is have a page separated from store function .. like this ..

**ROUTE**

```
Route::get('/loans', 'LoanController@viewLoanForm');
Route::post('/loans', 'LoanController@store');
```

**LoanController**

```
public function viewLoanForm()
{
    return view('loan');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    // process your input
    return redirect('/loans');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your `return` method like:

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {   $id = Auth::id();
           $loan=New loan;
            $loan->cod_user=$id;
            $loan->nume =$request->name;
            $loan->data=$request->date;
            $loan->durata=$request->period;
            $loan->valoare_rata_luna=$request->month;
            $loan->valoare_totala=$request->amount;
            $loan->save();

            return redirect()->route('loans');
        }
```